# Why does a flex container shrink when applying display: flex to body?

Tags: css, flexbox

I'm making an observation more so than stating a problem, if only to help anyone who's also noticed. I'm following a tutorial on flexbox when I accidently comment out display: flex on body{}. The container expands from 120px (flex-direction: column) wide to 100% of the viewport, horizontally. Display: grid also expands to 100% of the horizontal viewport. This observation is enough for me to post the question because I struggle working with flexbox and I end up applying padding and margin manually. I wonder if anyone else has any observations that are not explicitly stated in flexbox documentation.

```
<div class="flex-container">
    <div class="item">item 1</div>
    <div class="item">item 2</div>
    <div class="item">item 3</div>
  </div>
```

```
.flex-container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
}

 .item {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

Why does display: flex shrink the container?

Answer (score 1):

When an element has `display: flex` applied—making it a flex container—certain default settings come into play. Two of these settings are `flex-direction: row` on the container and [`flex-basis: auto`](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-flexbox-1/#flex-basis-property) on the items.

With `display: flex` on the `body` element, the flex item (`.flex-container`) is automatically set to `flex-basis: auto`, which is the width of the content. That's why the nested container "shrinks".

When `display: flex` is removed, the `body` element reverts back to `display: block`. Its child (`.flex-container`) is no longer a flex item and takes the [default `width: 100%` of block elements](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46546152/3597276).

If you want a flex item to expand to 100% width, just give it `flex-grow: 1` or `flex: 1`.

```css
body {
  display: flex;
}

.flex-container {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid red;
}

.item {
  background-color: blue;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100px;
  width: 100px;
  margin: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="flex-container">
  <div class="item">item 1</div>
  <div class="item">item 2</div>
  <div class="item">item 3</div>
</div>
```